# Looking for jquery volume button, not slider

Tags: jquery

Wonder if there is a js plugin to control music volume? I have all functionality written, just need UI. Instead of standard slider, I would like to use 'radio' volume design (round button), or at least simple YouTube player style volume control. Shoot me a link if you know such plugin.

Comment: I hope this may useful for you Check this : http://www.jquery.wisdomplug.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-utilities-plugins-jquery-plugins/jquery-media-plugin/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [jQuery UI split button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton). You can use it on div:

```
<div id="volume">
    <button id="up">+</button>
    <button id="down">-</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#up')
    .button()
    .click(function() {
        // up clicked
    })
    .next()
    .button()
    .click(function() {
        // down clicked
    })
    .parent()
    .buttonset();
```